# How to use simulate(click) function in react unit test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am beginner level in React test.

I have a component like a small carousel. I want to test if change state(currentPage) when i click. But i didn't. It throws that error message:

> Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found
>   instead.

I didnt understand " what is node,which node ? "

That is my test code :

```
it("check if next button works properly", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<QuickStartGuide />);
    const nextButton = wrapper.find(".quick-start-guide-messages-control-button .next-button");
    nextButton.simulate('click');

    expect(wrapper.state().currentIndex).toEqual(1);
})
```

And component :

```
<div className={containerClassName}>
    {isOpen &&
    <div className={"quick-start-guide-content-wrapper"}>
      <div className="quick-start-guide-header">
        <MtButton text={"MINIMIZE"}
                  hasIcon={true}
                  onClick={this.handleTriggerButtonClick}
                  className={"quick-start-guide-minimize-button"}/>

        <div className={"quick-start-guide-title"}>{"Quick Start Guide"}</div>

        {!!guideMessages.length &&
        <Fragment>
          <div className={"quick-start-guide-messages"}>
            <MtButton className={"quick-start-guide-messages-control-button prev-button"}
                      hasIcon={true}
                      onClick={this.handleGoToPrevMessageButtonClick}
                      isDisabled={!currentGuideMessageIndex}
                      text={"PREV"}/>

            {guideMessages[currentGuideMessageIndex][0]}

            <MtButton className={"quick-start-guide-messages-control-button next-button"}
                      hasIcon={true}
                      onClick={this.handleGoToNextMessageButtonClick}
                      isDisabled={currentGuideMessageIndex >= guideMessages.length - 1}
                      text={"NEXT"}/>
          </div>

          <div className={"quick-start-guide-indicators"}>
            {guideMessages.map((item, index) => (
              <IndicatorItem key={item[0].key}
                             order={index}
                             onClick={this.handleIndicatorItemClick}
                             className={classNames({
                               active: index === currentGuideMessageIndex
                             })}/>
            ))}
          </div>
        </Fragment>}
      </div>

      <div className={"quick-start-guide-content"}>
        <div className={"quick-start-guide-action-buttons"}>
          {guideActions.map(([text, handleActionButtonClick, isDisabled = false]) => (
            <MtButton key={text}
                      text={text}
                      isDisabled={isDisabled}
                      visualType={BUTTON_VISUAL_TYPES.ROUNDED}
                      className={"quick-start-guide-action-button"}
                      onClick={handleActionButtonClick}/>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>}

    <MtButton className={"uick-start-guide-trigger-button"}
              text={"GUIDE"}
              onClick={this.handleTriggerButtonClick}
              hasIcon={true}/>
  </div>
```

Comment: You need to share code of ```QuickStartGuide```. So we can't know what problem is

Comment: I added component code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving isn't related to the `simulate(click)` and is an issue with your selector because it's not finding anything to actually click.

Double check that this is the correct selector to use: `wrapper.find(".quick-start-guide-messages-control-button .next-button");`.

You can use `console.log(wrapper.debug())` to check to see what elements are available to select.